# Handling huge GeoJSON data

Tags: reactjs, performance, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I have a map application which uses around 6 geoJSON files. Those files amount to about 60mb static and 18mb when gzipped. Until now these are placed in src which increases bundle size to 18.4mb(out of which 18mb is geoJSON data).

What would be the best way to transfer these files to client. I can use localstorage but it has limitation of space.

I can use a backend service to provide me these data but transferring huge data might cause slowdown of the app.

Please suggest.

Comment: [Vector tiles](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/custom-vector-from-shapefile-geojson/).

Comment: Do you need this data at one time? I doubt you can dynamically read this data. See here [dynamiccustom-data-loading](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#dynamiccustom-data-loading)
You can also use [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

Comment: All files are not needed at one. Depending on user interaction and zoom levels, I toggle between the geoJSONs. I'm not sure which of the above plugins work but thanks, you gave some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what points you are displaying, you might only need some of the coords.

If you see for example, Google Maps, they do a request to a backend service every time you type in a letter in an input. All depends on what you are showing. Also, i don't think that any browser can handle 60mb of json data loaded at once and represented in the view without collapsing.

If the minimum amount of needed points is still very large, i'd try with a service worker to provide some kind of offline experience. First time you will have a big loading time but thats all. Afterwards you can update clients remotely.

To manage large amount of data in the backend, you got things like bigQuery or elasticsearch.

Comment: It is geoJSON of polygons about 200 areas on map. Each of them well defined boundaries which makes those files large.